# How to setup modpagespeed working with https CDN

Tags: https, cdn, mod-pagespeed

My website: `http://www.bestpricevn.com` get css/js/image from a CDN: `http://mycdn.cloudfront.net` (this CDN will go back to `http://www.bestpricevn.com` to get the original resources)

My setting:

```
 ModPagespeedDomain `mycdn.cloudfront.net`
 ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain `http://localhost` `http://mycdn.cloudfront.net`
```

ModPagespeed is OK to work based on this setting. But now I want to change my website from http version to `https://www.bestpricevn.com`, the CDN is changed to `https://mycdn.cloudfront.net`

My new setting:

```
ModPagespeedDomain `mycdn.cloudfront.net`
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain `http://localhost` `https://mycdn.cloudfront.net`
```

Now the Modpagespeed is not working, the resources (css/js/image) are not rewritten

Any body has a solution?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?